# If $T$ is compact, then $c_k\to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\{e_k\}$ be a orthonormal basis. Assume that the sequence $\{c_k\}$ is complex numbers. Show that if $T\in L(H, H)$ defined by $Tx=\sum_{k} c_k(x,e_k)e_k$ is compact, then $c_k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$

> I can prove the converse statement (if $c_k\to 0$, then $T$ is compact): note that let $T_nx=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k(x,e_k)e_k$ and consider
> $$
> \|(T-T_n)x\|^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \|c_k(x,e_k)e_k\|^2\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|c_k||(x,e_k)|\le \sup|c_k|\|x\|\to 0
> $$

I try to prove it by contradiction. If $c_k$ does not go to $0$, then for $\epsilon>0$, there is a subsequence $\{c_{kj}\}$ with $|c_{kj}|>\epsilon$. Take a bounded sequence $\{e_{kj}\}$ with norm $1$ (standard basis), consider
$$
\|T(e_{kj})-T(e_{ki})\|^2=\|c_{kj}e_{kj}-c_{ki}e_{ki}\|^2= |c_{kj}|^2+|c_{ki}|^2\ge 2\epsilon
$$

Comment: If $T $ is compact and a sequence $u_n$ is convergent to $0$ convergent to $0$ weakly then $Tu_n$ is convergent to $0$ with respect to the norm. Take $u_n=e_n.$ By the Parseval identity it is convergent to $0$ weakly. Hence $Te_n=c_ne_n$ is convergent in norm. Hence $c_n=\|Te_n\|\to 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may also suppose, by going to a  subsequence , that $(T(e_{kj}))=c_{kj}e_{kj}$ converges. Hence,  $\|Te_{kj}-Te_{kl}\|=\|c_{kj}e_{kj}-c_{kl}e_{kj}\|\to 0$. But  $\|c_{kj}e_{kj}-c_{kl}e_{kj}\|^{2}=c_{kj}^{2}+c_{kl}^{2} \geq 2 \epsilon^{2}$. a contardiction.

Comment: So $\{Te_{kj}\}$ does not have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @Hermi